# Angular: How am I supposed to use here the routerLink to navigate in my app?

Tags: angular, typescript

So I have this url: `http://localhost:3000/companies` and I would like to use routerLink to navigate to pages `http://localhost:3000/companies/:id` after clicking on an `<a>` tag.

I have this component:

```
<div class="container">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button class="navbar-toggle collapsed" (click)="isNavbarCollapsed = !isNavbarCollapsed">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a routerLink="/" class="navbar-brand">{{title}}</a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse" [collapse]="isNavbarCollapsed" id="navbar">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li [class.active]="router.isActive('/cards', false)"> <a routerLink="/cards">Cards</a> </li>
                    <li [class.active]="router.isActive('/companies', false)"> <a routerLink="/companies">Companies</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="col-lg-12 panel panel-default">
        <h3>{{currentPageTitle | async}}</h3>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have this in my module:

```
let routes: Route[] = [
    { path: "companies", component: CompanyPageComponent },
    { path: "cards", component: CardPageComponent },
    { path: "companies/:id", component: CompanyPageComponent },
    { path: "cards/:id", component: CardPageComponent },
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule, RouterModule.forRoot(routes), FormsModule, HttpModule, CollapseModule.forRoot()],
    declarations: [BusinessCardAppComponent, CompanyPageComponent, CardPageComponent],
    exports: [],
    providers: [CardService, CompanyService],
    bootstrap: [BusinessCardAppComponent]
})
```

And in my CompanyPageComponent I got the following:

```
export class CompanyPageComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private companyService: CompanyService,
        private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
            let companyId = +params['id'];
            // TODO: get current company by ID
        });
    }
}
```

And the `<a>` tag I am supposed to use it: `<a> Company name... </a>`

I spent a couple of hours how to make it work but can't find a way... Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this to build the link:

```
<a routerLink="/companies/{{ id }}">Company name</a>
```

On the destination component to get the url's id:

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute){}

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.params.subscribe( (params: Params) => {
         console.log(params.id) 
    });
}
```

Be aware that `params.id` will be a String so you if you need a number you'd need to transform.